# String that can contain multiple numbers - how do I extract the longest number?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string that

- contains at least one number
- can contain multiple numbers

Some examples are:

```
https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=53199604568&id=218700384
https://www.facebook.com/username_13/posts/101505775425651120
https://www.facebook.com/username/posts/101505775425699820
```

I need a way to extract the longest number from the string. So for the 3 strings above, it would extract

```
53199604568
101505775425651120
101505775425699820
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#get the lines first
text = <<ENDTEXT
https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=53199604568&id=218700384
https://www.facebook.com/username_13/posts/101505775425651120
https://www.facebook.com/username/posts/101505775425699820
ENDTEXT
lines = text.split("\n")

#this bit is the actual answer to your question
lines.collect{|line| line.scan(/\d+/).sort_by(&:length).last}
```

Note that i'm returning the numbers as strings here.  You could convert them to numbers with to_i

Comment: 1.9 has a `max_by` method, so you could do `line.scan(/\d+/).max_by(&:length)`.

Comment: 1.9 also has a .lines method, so you end up with something like `text.lines.map{|line| line.scan(/\d+/).max_by(&:to_i)}`

Answer (score 0):

parse the list (to get an int array), then use the Max function. array.Max for syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=53199604568&id=218700384"
s.scan(/\d+/).max{|a,b| a.length <=> b.length}.to_i
```

Comment: Note that if you're to_i'ing the strings anyway, then you could simply sort based on the integer value - longer strings mean larger integers.